# Time Estimate for Backup Recovery with IBM System x3650 M3

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, ibm, backup-restoration, windows-server-backup

I've been doing a little business continuity planning research for myself and I have come to the question of:

*What is the estimated time for the recovery of about 4 TB worth of data with the use of Windows Server Backup?*

The system that is to be used is an **IBM System x3650 M3**. This appliance has an Intel Xeon CPU @ 2.49 GHz 2.39 GHz. [Here's a link for the server.](http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/ph/x/hardware/rack/x3650m3/specs.html)

I know that there may not be people who have undergone the exact same situation illustrated above but what are some *estimates* from those that are experienced in this?

The data is stored on local hard drives.

Comment: What is the back up stored on? Local? USB disk? SAN? DVD? Tape?  I think this question is interesting -- a good answer would provide a method for *estimating* recovery times for any server.

Comment: Hi there! Forgot to mention this part. I will be editing the post for easy reading for all.